# How to configure Metro for running React Native packager/bundler on different server port?

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native, expo

I configured Metro to run React Native packager/bundler on a different port as 8081 is being used by McAfee service and I can't kill this process on my Mac.

I changed the default port to different one in Xcode script/files etc. But the react metro server(packager/bundler) i had to manually start every time before running the App. However with following edit in your MetroConfig.js file, if you run the App, then Metro server will automatically run on a different port specified in this file

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');
const portConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

portConfig.server.port = 8088;
module.exports = portConfig;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry! My code is correct... it wasn't working yesterday because of some other issue. Once i fixed that, this config is working fine :)

Before customizing Metro file, I had to manually start Metro Packager(from the terminal) whenever  I was launching the React Native App from Xcode. However once I configured the Metro, the Packager/bundler is starting automatically when I run the App from Xcode... so all good now!

Comment: Can you put this answer as edit on your question